# jquery show hidden text once a time

Tags: jquery

Still a student in jquery so I'm eager to learn new stuff.

Ok here's the problem I'm encountering at the moment. But don't know where to start to solve it.

What I want to achieve is to create this cloud of buttons with hidden tex, make them show but hides as soon I push another button. I've tried the toggle but my knowledge of JS is to limited. Anybody want to help me out? Thx

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.img-swap').click(function () {
        $('p.werkTxt').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

Comment: pls provide html snippet as well

Comment: You need to post your html also.

Answer (score 0):

This will be my thoughts on how to do this:
1. on the button click event handler
    hide all the button text first, then show the current button text
2. on the button mouse out event handler -- not sure if you want to do this though
    show all the button text

for more detailed codes, you need to provide the HTML snippet as people suggested